# How to find the monthly mean of decimal-date data in R

Tags: r, lubridate

as always any help appreciated. I've got daily data (2 observations per day) for lake depth. I have already converted the dates to decimal_date format e.g. 2000.003 for 2nd Jan 2000 but need to create a time series of monthly mean anomaly - one value per month. I've attached a copy of the first few data in the data frame if it helps to visualise.

```
Decim_Date  Depth (cm)  Anomaly (cm)
1   2000.000    1216    78.6721
2   2000.000    1216    78.6721
3   2000.003    1216    78.6721
4   2000.003    1217    79.6721
5   2000.005    1216    78.6721
6   2000.005    1216    78.6721
7   2000.008    1215    77.6721
8   2000.008    1216    78.6721
9   2000.011    1215    77.6721
10  2000.011    1216    78.6721
```

I'm very stuck! Thanks in advance

Comment: use `by` with `month(Ddate)` and `year(Ddate)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not sure I follow! Sorry! I'm relatively new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested or with a similar problem, I have figured out the answer and posted below. Note: the L.Vic and L.Kyg in the code refer to two lakes with the data in a data frame as per above question.

```
require("lubridate"); require("xts"); require("plyr") 

# Convert to xts format and then apply monthly mean upon anomalies
x <- xts(L.Vic[,-1], as.POSIXct(L.Vic[,1], format="%d-%b-%y"))
x <- apply.monthly(x$Anomaly_cm, mean)
y <- xts(L.Kyg[,-1], as.POSIXct(L.Kyg[,1], format="%d-%b-%y"))
y <- apply.monthly(y$Anomaly_cm, mean)

# Converts xts row.names to column format and saves as data frame
L.Vic.ts <- data.frame(date=index(x), coredata(x))
L.Kyg.ts <- data.frame(date=index(y), coredata(y))

# Change to 'yyyy-mm' format, then a POSIXct date-time object, then dec-date  
L.Vic.ts$date <- strftime(strptime(L.Vic.ts$date, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m")
L.Vic.ts$date <- parse_date_time(L.Vic.ts$date, "ym") 
L.Vic.ts$date <- decimal_date(L.Vic.ts$date)
colnames(L.Vic.ts) <- c("Decim_Date", "SWSanom")
L.Kyg.ts$date <- strftime(strptime(L.Kyg.ts$date, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m")
L.Kyg.ts$date <- parse_date_time(L.Kyg.ts$date, "ym") 
L.Kyg.ts$date <- decimal_date(L.Kyg.ts$date)
colnames(L.Kyg.ts) <- c("Decim_Date", "SWSanom")
```

Hope this helps, cheers